# Inequality involving a 0-probability event

Tags: probability

Let $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_N\}$ be a set of points sampled i.i.d. from some distribution $P$. Let $A(x) \in \{true, false\}$.

If $\exists x \in S$ s.t. A(x) is true, then does it follow that $P_{x\sim P}[A(x)]>0$?

Comment: Is $X$ a discrete random variable or a continuous random variable?

Comment: It can be either. I'm less clear when P is a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

For example, suppose the distribution is standard normal, and define $A(x)$ as true for $x = 1$ and false for all other $x$. Then the probability that $A(x)$ is true for a new draw from the distribution is $0$, because the probability that a random standard normal deviate equals $1$ is also $0$.

The trick here is that although $A(x)$ is not false for **all** $x ∈ ℝ$, it is false [almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) on $ℝ$. Thus, it is [almost surely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) false.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.**

OK, I am a little provocative here. Kodiologist’s answer above is ok: a normal sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with $A(x_1)$ true and $A(x)$ false for all $x \ne x_1$ gives *some kind of* counterexample.

However, the following is true as well: given $A(x)$ (measurable) taking values true/false, if $\mathbb P(A(X)) = 0$ when $X$ follows the specified distribution, then $P(A(X_1) \text{ or } \dots \text{ or } A(X_n)) = 0$ when $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent with this distribution.

That is, while technically Kodiologist is right, the probability of being in this situation if the predicate $A(\cdot)$ is fixed beforehand is 0...

I’ll defend this paradox:

- The point is that you cannot use a sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$ to make inference on a predicate $A(\cdot)$ which is defined *after* the sampling. If $A(\cdot)$ is defined *before* the sampling, and if for some sampled $x_i$ $A(x_i)$ holds, you’ll *never* get wrong in concluding that $\mathbb P(A(X)) > 0$.
- Imagine that there is a bet to be made on $\mathbb P(A(X))$. The predicate $A$ is fixed (but we don’t see its definition) and we sample a finite number of values $x_i$ in a normal distribution (say), and we observe that for at least one of the sampled values $A(x_i)$ holds. I bet that $\mathbb P(A(X)) > 0$. Is anyone willing to bet anything on the contrary?
- I am not telling that the statement "$\exists x$ in the support of the distribution of $X$ s.t. $A(x)$ holds $\Rightarrow \mathbb P(A(X)) > 0$" is true. It could not be more wrong. This is all about the fact that $x$ is assumed to be sampled in the distribution of $X$.

Comment: Wouldn't this argument result in concluding that conditional probabilities based on events of probability zero can be ignored because the events they are conditioned on almost surely do not happen?

Comment: You're basically right: I chose a pathological $A$ and the conjecture would hold for suitably well-behaved classes of $P$ and $A$. But since @axk put no restrictions on these, I gave an answer for the general case.

Comment: @whuber I certainly wouldn’t discard a question on $\mathbb P(X>0 | Y =y)$ where $(X,Y)$ is, say, a normal vector. Honestly I don’t see anything disputable in my answer. It’s not about *pathological* predicate The point is that you cannot use a sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$ to make inference on a predicate $A(\cdot)$ which is defined *after* the sampling. If $A(\cdot)$ is defined *before* the sampling, and if for some sampled $x_i$ $A(x_i)$ holds, you’ll *never* get wrong in concluding that $\mathbb P(A(X)) > 0$.

Comment: I inserted this clarification in my answer.

Comment: Please forgive me for possibly misinterpreting: I read your assertion as saying that one can make no inferences about quantities like $\Pr(A(X)|X)$, but since that's obviously incorrect I must be missing some qualification or assumption you are making.

Comment: I am just telling that if you (first) fix a predicate $A$ such that $Pr(A(X)) = 0$, then sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$, with probability 1 $A(x_i)$ is false for all $i$. Using this I pretend that if some $A(x_i)$ holds, certainly $Pr(A(X)) > 0$.

Comment: @whuber Imagine that there is a bet to be made. $A$ is fixed (but we don’t see its definition) and we sample, say, one hundred values in a normal distribution, and we observe that for at least one of the sampled values $A(x_i)$ holds. I bet that the set $\{x : A(x)\}$ has positive measure. Are you willing to bet anything on the contrary?

Comment: Thank you; that helps clarify what you are thinking. Note that there is a distinction between mathematical models of reality and how data really behave. In practice, we never observe real numbers: we have only discrete approximations to them. In that sense all nonempty sets automatically have positive probabilities. However, that really says nothing about the underlying mathematics. So long as you are clear that you are not making a mathematical statement you will be ok. (But then one might question the utility of abandoning the theory that underlies most of statistics...)

Comment: @whuber as a (former) constructivist, I couldn’t agree more...

Comment: @whuber I am making a mathematical statement, it is "given $A(x)$ (measurable) taking values true/false, if $\mathbb P(A(X)) = 0$ when $X$ follows the specified distribution, then $P(A(X_1) \text{ or } \dots \text{ or } A(X_n)) = 0$ when $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent with this distribution." What we can discuss is wether it answers the question or not...

Comment: Thank you @Elvis and whuber. It does answer my intended question, and seeing both Elvis' answer Kodiologist's answer together with this discussion helped me see what I was missing. So basically the predicate is fixed beforehand and measurable, I just didn't realise that this was important when I formulated the question.